# How do I deliver variables to a theme function?

Tags: 7, views, theming, hooks

I'm struggling to complete my first Views display plugin. Currently I'm at a stage where the theming stuff is not working.

```
function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'myfunc' => array(
      'variables' => array(
        'view' => NULL,
        'options' => array(),
        'rows' => array(),
        'title' => NULL,
      )
    )
  );
}

function theme_myfunc($variables) {
  // $variables are null
  $view = $variables['view'];
  $options = $variables['options'];
  $rows = $variables['rows'];
  $title = $variables['title'];
  // ...
}
```

The variables are obviously null in `theme_myfunc()`. I don't know how I'm supposed to deliver them from the view object to theme functions.

Should I implement any of the `template_preprocess()` functions by any chance?

Comment: I recommend that you check out this tutorial: http://groups.drupal.org/node/10129